# Mysql error 1064 stored procedure error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
create function sf_get_empsallist(dname varchar(100))
returns varchar(300)
begin
declare emplist varchar(300) default '';
declare flag int default 0 ;
declare name varchar(100);
declare sal int;
declare c1 cursor  for
select ename,salary from emp join dept
on emp.deptid=dept.deptid
where deptname=dname;
declare continue handler for not found set flag=1;
open c1;
myloop: loop
fetch c1 into name,sal;
if flag=1 then
leave myloop;
end if;
set emplist=concat(emplist,',',name,'-',sal);
end loop;
return(substr(emplist,2));
close c1;
end
$$
```

The error i m getting is

> ```
> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 4
> ```

I tried by best at getting it solved but couldn't find it.

Comment: Do you have `DELIMITER $$` before this?

Comment: yes the delimiter is $$

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: i m using mysql 8.0 which mysql are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql 5.5.

Comment: actually in mysql 8.0 we have to set SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1; to use no sql function procedure

Comment: the problem is solved ,as i m new Barmar can you closed this thread?

Comment: Post the solution as an answer. You're allowed to answer your own question.

Comment: I don't think it's the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` setting, though. That should cause a different error, not a syntax error.

Comment: but any way it solved the error

Answer (score 2):

```
delimiter $$
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
create function sf_get_empsallist(dname varchar(100))
returns varchar(300)
begin
declare emplist varchar(300) default '';
declare flag int default 0 ;
declare name varchar(100);
declare sal int;
declare c1 cursor  for
select ename,salary from emp join dept
on emp.deptid=dept.deptid
where deptname=dname;
declare continue handler for not found set flag=1;
open c1;
myloop: loop
fetch c1 into name,sal;
if flag=1 then
leave myloop;
end if;
set emplist=concat(emplist,',',name,'-',sal);
end loop;
return(substr(emplist,2));
close c1;
end
$$
```